# How to Embed MVC3 Website within a normal asp.net website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-3.5

We have an existing MVC3 application developed by a 3rd party. We also have an existing asp.net application developed on framework 3.5. I have a requirement to display the MVC3 application pages on the ASP.NET pages.

Is it possible?
If yes, will there be any possibility for the communication between two? Say I click on a button in ASP.NET webpage, should pass a parameter to the MVC3 application.

Comment: Sure. That can be done. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this at the company i'm currently working. We have a shoppingcart in MVC3 and the normal website with some features in asp. we've just added the MVC as a sub application in IIS.

Both applications share the same cookies for login. You can just pass your parameters as post or get request, store them in a cookie or in a session.

We just link between sites and it's working great. everyone thinks it's the same application